# Process Builder - Email notification only when lookup field changes from null to value

Tags: process-builder, lookup

Process Builder to end email alert.

1 ) When Look(User) changes from NULL to Value the Send email alert to New Value

2 ) When look(user) changes from Value to NULL send mail to old value.

Comment: did you try to create a condition testing if the Value Changed and if the old value is Empty or equal a null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula, before sending the email:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED( FIELD ),
    PRIORVALUE( FIELD ) = NULL
)
```

Comment: This one is working fine but we have send one more mail when we make lookup(User) field null then send email to old value of lookup(user). How do we achieve this to send mail to old value